# jQuery toggle() only engages on the 2ND double-click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function, toggle

I want to be able to double-click on my icon and have it toggle that a user has liked a post. I have added the jQuery toggle function but it only engages after the 2ND double-click. After that it works just fine. I wanted to ask what I might be missing.

```js
$(document).on('dblclick', '.likeButton', function() {
  $('.likes span').text('Andrew').toggle();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="likeBar">
        <ul>
          <li class="heart">
            <i class="likeButton fas fa-heart fa-lg"></i>
          </li>
          <li class="likes">
            <span></span>
  
          </li>
          <li class="moreInfo">
            <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h fa-lg"></i>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: I think the `<` character in the `<===` might be throwing off the parser

Comment: It works fine. The first double click/toggle hides it. Add css rule `.likes span{display:none}` and you will see it the first time because it will show the span instead of hide it. Not sure that using `toggle()` is what you really want here

Answer (score -1):

You can change your jquery code to this. In this code I use an "if" instead toggle.

```js
$(document).on('dblclick', '.likeButton', function() {
    if($('.likes span').text() == '')
        $('.likes span').text('Andrew');
    else
        $('.likes span').text('');
})
```

It works for me.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to be working. It still takes a second dblclick to activate.

Comment: Your trigger is inside the event handler so it will create infinite loop. Not likely you can trigger it on page load either if OP is using event delegation which usually implies the elements don't exist on page load

Comment: I edited my answer and use "if" instead toggle. It worked for me.